# Why is the dimension of U one less than $P_4(F)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem from Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler, Exercise 2.C.4a

Problem:

Let $U =$ { $p \in P_4(F) : p(6) = 0$}. Find a Basis of U.

The solution to 4a is found here: https://linearalgebras.com/2c.html

In particular, the solution shown for 4a I can get by taking a known basis of $P_4(F)$, $b_1=(1,x,x^{2},x^{3},x^{4})$.
Because of the condition of U, $p(x)$ must be divisble by $x-6$ and scalar multiplying it by $x-6 \in F$ produces $b_2=(x-6,x^{2}-6x,x^{3}-6x^{2},x^{4}-6x^{3},x^{5}-6x^{4})$. The fifth vector in $b_2$ is dropped because the degree of that polynomial is 5, and the fact that $p \in P_4(F)$ means the basis can only contain a polynomial of degree 4 or less.

Hence we now have a vector $b_3=(x-6,x^{2}-6x,x^{3}-6x^{2},x^{4}-6x^{3})$. Now if we prove linear independence and $span(b_3) = U$, we are done with 4a. I'm comfortable that this is a linearly independent set of vectors because they are all polynomials of different degrees, but what is not clear is how to prove $span(b_3) = U$.

Any help on intuition of why U is one degree less than $P_4(F)$ (as well as any problems with my work so far) is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would probably rather use the basis $(1,x-6,(x-6)^2,(x-6)^3,(x-6)^4)$ for $P_4(x)$. It works better with everything.

Comment: True. Then you can drop 1 because that violates U's need of $p(6) = 0$. Still lost on how this spans U though.

Comment: You have shown that 1) $U$ has dimension at least $\dim(P_4(x))-1$, and 2) $U$ is not all of $P_4(x)$. This by itself is enough.

Comment: Excellent, I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have four linearly independent vectors in a four-dimensional space, they automatically span the space. The space is four-dimensional because it can't be five-dimensional (as then it would be all of $P_4(F)$).

The intuition is that you have a subspace of $5$-space cut out by a single linear equation, so the resulting space has dimension $5-1 = 4$ (it's a so-called hyperplane). This is analogous to the situation in three dimensions, where a subspace defined by a single equation $ax + by + cz = 0$ yields a plane, i.e., you lose one dimension. The same holds generically: if you have $k$ independent equations in $n$-space, then the subspace consisting of all solutions has dimension $n-k$.

Comment: The last sentience of your first paragraph drove it home. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $p\in U$. The key is what you mentioned, that this is equivalent to saying $(x-6)|p$ or, equivalently, $p=(x-6)q$ for some $q\in P_3(F)$.
Take the coefficients of $q$ to express $p$ in basis $b_3$.

Comment: I see, so because of the criterion of U you're basically dividing out one of the dimensions? Thank you for the response.